# Regex format for a particular Match

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to write a regex for the following format

**PA-123456-067_TY**

It's always `PA`, followed by a dash, 6 digits, another dash, then 3 digits, and ends with `_TY`

Apparently, when I write this regex to match the above format it shows the output correctly

```
^[^[PA]-]+-(([^-]+)-([^_]+))_([^.]+)
```

with all the **Negation symbols ^**

This does not work if I write the regex in the below format without negation symbols

```
[[PA]-]+-(([-]+)-([_]+))_([.]+)
```

Can someone explain to me why is this so?

Comment: [`^PA-[0-9]+-[0-9]+_[A-Z]+$`](https://regex101.com/r/etBCEt/1)?

Comment: Is your string always `PA` followed by 6 digits then 3 digits then ends with `_TY`? If so this will work `PA-(\d){6}-(\d){3}_TY`

Comment: Yes.Its always PA follwed by 6 digts and then 3 digits and ends with _TY

Comment: I think that the first pattern also does not match https://regex101.com/r/aHHttL/1

Comment: If you haven't discovered it already, may I suggest https://regex101.com/. If you need a Java specific one then https://www.freeformatter.com/java-regex-tester.html or https://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html would work

Comment: Then use [`^PA-[0-9]{6}-[0-9]{3}_TY\.$`](https://regex101.com/r/etBCEt/2)

Comment: Then this should work `PA-(\d){6}-(\d){3}_TY` for what you need. https://regexr.com/4n9dk

Comment: @Thefourthbird is correct. whatever you are wanting to happen is not what you expect that regex doesn't match on the provided text. and the "nots" are not doing what you think. one of these solutions provided should be easier to understand

Comment: https://www.freeformatter.com/java-regex-tester.html#ad-output         I have tested it here and its working

Comment: this is java specific one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The negation symbol means that the character cannot be anything within the specified class. Your regex is much more complicated than it needs to be and is therefore obfuscating what you really want.

You probably want something like this:

`^PA-(\d+)-(\d+)_TY$`

... which matches anything that starts with `PA-`, then includes two groups of numbers separated by a dash, then an underscore and the letters `TY`. If you want everything after the `PA` to be what you capture, but separated into the three groups, then it's a little more abstract:

`^PA-(.+)-(.+)_(.+)$`

This matches:

- `PA-`
- a capture group of any characters
- a dash
- another capture group of any characters
- an underscore
- all the remaining characters until end-of-line

Character classes `[...]` are saying match any single character in the list, so your first capture group `(([^-]+)-([^_]+))` is looking for anything that isn't a dash any number of times followed by a dash (which is fine) followed by anything that isn't an underscore (again fine). Having the extra set of parentheses around that creates another capture group (probably group 1 as it's the first parentheses reached by the regex engine)... that part is OK but probably makes interpreting the answer less intuitive in this case.

In the re-write however, your first capture group `(([-]+)-([_]+))` matches `[-]+`, which means "one or more dashes" followed by a dash, followed by any number of underscores followed by an underscore. Since your input does not have a dash immediately following `PA-`, the entire regex fails to find anything.

Putting the `PA` inside embedded character classes is also making things complicated. The first part of your first one is looking for, well, I'm not actually sure how `[^[PA]-]+` is interpreted in practice but I suspect it's something like "not either a P or an A or a dash any number of times". The second one is looking for the opposite, I think. But you don't want any of that, you just want to start without anything other than the actual sequence of characters you care about, which is just `PA-`.

Update: As per the clarifications in the comments on the original question, knowing you want fixed-size groups of digits, it would look like this:

`^PA-(\d{6})-(\d{3})_TY$`

That captures `PA-`, then a 6-digit number, then a dash, then a 3-digit number, then `_TY`. The six digit number and 3 digit numbers will be in capture groups 1 and 2, respectively.

If the sizes of those numbers could ever change, then replace `{x}` with `+` to just capture numbers regardless of max length.

Comment: I need all those extra brackets to extract different sets of data from all the groups in the regex for my pratical implementation.

Comment: If you want to *capture* those groups, the outer brackets should be parentheses, something like: `(PA-)- ...`. Square brackets *only* means "treat any of the following characters as a single character for matching purposes". However, if this regex matched, you already know the starting characters are `PA-`. Capture groups are generally only used when you *don't* know what characters will be in them.

Comment: ... and if anyone knows what `[[PA]-]` will match, I'd love to hear it... I've never seen character classes embedded in other character classes before and am a little surprised the regex even compiles.

Answer (score 1):

according to your comment this would be appropriate `PA-\d{6}-\d{3}_TY`

EDIT: if you want to match a line use it with anchors: `^PA-\d{6}-\d{3}_TY$`

Comment: Don't forget the anchors. Also, why `[\d]` instead of simply `\d`?

Comment: What is the difference between ^PA and PA in the regex which you have used

Comment: `^` just means "at the start of the line"

Comment: @acus `^` asserts position at he start of the line, `$` at the end, this way it matches only if the whole line is exactly as specified